# Lilypond install not working

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm trying to install Lilypond on a 32-bit system, and for some reason the `sh` file simply does not want to execute itself.
I'm completely new to Ubuntu, so I have next to no knowledge of how anything works. But I've looked around and tried a few things. I've checked "allow executing file as program" in Properties, but I don't see any option of executing the file, only opening it with `gedit` or Libreoffice writer.

I've tried,

```
chmod u+x lilypond
```

and

```
chmod u+x lilypond-2.18.2-1.linux-x86.sh
```

but both times it said

```
chmod: cannot access [filename I entered]. No such file or directory
```

I've seen a suggestion for something like:

```
cd /path/to/file  
chmod +x filename.sh  
./filename.sh
```

but I don't even know how to make a command line with more than one line. 
Does anyone know what I can do?.

Comment: Run the above commands separately(ie, one by one)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a specific version of lilypond, just execute the following to install a [stable version of lilypond](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=lilypond):

> sudo apt-get install lilypond

Alternatively, use the `software center` or `synaptic`to install lilypond.

The Ubuntu 14.04 package repository contains lilypond 2.16. The upcoming 14.10 will likely have lilypond 2.18.

In general, installing software "manually" (as you've tried) is only required in certain cases: for example, if you require a specific version that isn't available in the ubuntu software repositories, or if you want to install anything that's missing completely in the repos. So, it's usually the easiest way to check the software repositories (via `Software center` or `synaptic`) first.

Comment: I'm trying this and it seems to be working. Do you know whether this'll get me the stable or the unstable version? I'd prefer stable.

Comment: I'm almost sure it's a stable version, if you didn't change anything regarding package sources.

Answer (score 0):

Succinctly, you will need to

1. Open the terminal program (CTRL+ALT+T in Ubuntu).

   Change to the directory that contains the file that you downloaded. That is a done with a command with the following form:

   ```
   cd /home/username/Downloads
   ```

   (Naturally, you should substitute the file’s actual path
      for `/home/username/Downloads`.)

   The file you download (assuming it is the latest stable version of LilyPond) should be called `lilypond-2.18.2-1.linux-x86.sh`. You will need to ensure that is executable (able to be run as a command). To do this, type

   ```
   chmod +x lilypond-2.18.2-1.linux-x86.sh
   ```

   Now, run the installation script, using the following command:

   ```
   ./lilypond-2.18.2-1.linux-x86.sh
   ```

   If for some reason the installation script fails (it tends to do so when the 32-bit LilyPond is being installed on a 64-bit version of Linux), try using the following command instead:

   ```
   bash lilypond-2.18.2-1.linux-x86.sh
   ```

   If you accept all of the default options, the script will install LilyPond in a directory called `/home/username/lilypond` (where `username` represents your own user name). You will need to add this directory to your execution path, which is done by issuing the following command:

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/lilypond/usr/bin
   ```

   You will either need to issue this commend every time you want to use LilyPond after opening a new terminal window, or else add it to one of your startup scripts (e.g., `.bashrc`). To do this last step, type the following in your terminal window:

   ```
   echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/lilypond/usr/bin' >> ~/.bashrc
   ```

   (You can copy and paste this last command as-is.)

You should be good to go. To compile a file named, say, `music.ly`, type `lilypond music.ly` in a terminal window.